# Why does Django server crash in PyCharm professional?

Tags: python, django

I am working in PyCharm professional version and I am not able to run Django server from PyCharm, though I can start it from cmd.

After starting the server from cmd, everything works fine, I can reach my urls and get a response.
When I am trying to do the same from Pycharm, first I get a windows error ("Python has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.) When I click "Close the program", it does not close, and I can see the following in error in PyCharm:

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I am using the following versions:
Python version: 3.6.1
Django version: 1.9.13

I have already tried Tools | Run manage.py Task | runserver , which gives the same result.

I have found a way to make this error disappear in PyCharm:
When I go to Run | Edit Configurations |  and check "No reload", then the server starts normally and I can access it through the browser.

Does anyone have a hint on why this is happening? What is the purpose of "No reload"?

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: First, python 3.6 is not supported with django 1.9 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support)
You should use python version 3.5 or less.

The "No reload" is used to avoid to reload your test server automatically when you make changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if in Setting/Languages & Frameworks/Django the option Enable Django Support if selected,
then you should check if the routes to Django Project Root, Settings and manage.py are set correctly.

regards

Comment: These seem to be fine: the Django Support is enabled, and the routes are correct. It might be some compatibility issue... I have not found a solution yet, at least the server runs with the workaround.